# Access Microsoft Edge Legacy after installing the new version of Microsoft Edge

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-edge

I was trying to test one of my application on Microsoft edge browser in VM and due to some updates my Edge browser has been updated to Chromium version (latest version) and i was unable to downgrade it or unable to find any older version .

I have also tried following MSDN post for using both legacy and new version of Edge side by side by even though i follow those steps i was unable to see the old Edge legacy versions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-sysupdate-access-old-edge

Can some one suggest if there is any other work around to make this happen

Comment: Apparently there is no longer a way to have the legacy Edge in modern Windows, but there are official VMs available instead (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) for the very purpose of testing old browsers.

Answer (score 6):

From [the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-sysupdate-access-old-edge#best-practice-guidance), the **Allow Microsoft Edge Side by Side browser experience** should be enabled before the new version of Microsoft Edge is deployed to your users' devices.

So, I suggest you could try to **uninstall** the New Microsoft Edge from the Control Panel first, then, according the above article to enable the **Allow Microsoft Edge Side by Side browser experience** Group Policy. After that, please refer to the following steps the check the Registry and make sure the **Allowsxs** value is 1.

1. Press **WIN+R** keys together to open RUN dialog box. Now type **`regedit`** in RUN dialog box and press Enter. It'll open **Registry Editor**.
2. Go to following key: **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft`**
3. Find the **EdgeUpdate** Key (if not find this key, create a new key under **Microsoft** key and set its name as **EdgeUpdate**)
4. Select **EdgeUpdate** key and in right-side pane, right-click on empty area and select **New -> DWORD (32-bit) Value** option. Set the new DWORD name as **Allowsxs** and set its value to **1**.

Then, reinstall the [New Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge), you can open and use both Microsoft Edge web browsers.

Besides, some new updates can cause the Microsoft Edge Legacy shortcut in Start Menu not working or hide, if that is the case, please refer to the following steps to create a new shortcut to Legacy Microsoft Edge browser:

1. Press **WIN+R** keys together to launch RUN dialog box.
2. Now type **`shell:appsfolder`** in RUN dialog box and press Enter key.
3. It'll open Applications folder in File Explorer. Look for old Microsoft Edge application having old White icon.

   [image]

   Double-click on it and it'll launch old Microsoft Edge without any issue.

   Now you can right-click on the application and select Pin to Start, Pin to Taskbar or Create Shortcut option to add its shortcut to Start Menu, Taskbar or Desktop.

Comment: Hi, I tried the same in my VM but still unable to find the legacy version .

Comment: Please check the details steps from the following link: [Link 1](https://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-restore-old-legacy-microsoft-edge-browser-after-installing-new-edge-in-windows-10/) and [Link 2](https://www.askvg.com/fix-microsoft-edge-legacy-shortcut-not-working-in-windows-10-start-menu/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems we can't enable the legacy version in windows server VM.

Please follow the below discussion on this.

Thanks.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/tutorial-how-to-run-legacy-and-chromium-based-edge/m-p/1200283#M25430